# Simple Calculator trying to relearn C++. lvalue error

Tags: c++

Trying to make a simple Calculator. I've been trying to be as organized as I can with my .headers and .cpps because I remember back in the day those were important. Haha. I've smashed about 10 keyboards trying to get this to work.

```
CALCULATOR2.CPP
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "CalculatorDeclarations.h"
int firstInteger;
int secondInteger;
int theAnswer;
char factor;
int main()
{
    getFirstInteger(firstInteger);
    getSecondInteger(secondInteger);
    getFactor(factor);
    giveResults(theAnswer);
    return 0;
}

CalculatorDeclarations.h
#ifndef ADD_H
#define ADD_H
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
int getFirstInteger(int firstInteger);
int getSecondInteger(int secondInterger);
void getFactor(char factor);
int doCalculations(int getFirstInteger, int secondInterger, char getFactor);
int giveResults(int theAnswer);
#endif

CALCULATORSFUNCTIONS.CPP
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "CalculatorDeclarations.h";

int giveResults(int theAnswer)
{
    std::cout << theAnswer;
}
int getFirstInteger(int firstInteger)
{
    firstInteger;
    std::cout << "Please enter the first integer you would like to use." <<     std::endl;
    std::cin >> firstInteger;
    return firstInteger;
}

int getSecondInteger(int secondInteger)
{
    secondInteger;
    std::cout << "Please enter the second integer you would like to use." <<     std::endl;
    std::cin >> secondInteger;
    return secondInteger;
}

void getFactor(char factor)                                                                            
{
    factor;
    std::cout << "Select what you would like to use: (+, -, *, /)" <<    std::endl;
    std::cin >> factor;
}

int doCalculations(int firstInteger, int secondInterger, int getFactor)
{
    int theAnswer;
    if (getFactor == '+')
    {
        firstInteger + secondInterger = theAnswer;
        return theAnswer;
    }
    if (getFactor == '-')
    {
        firstInteger - secondInterger = theAnswer;
        return theAnswer;
    }
    if (getFactor == '*')
    {
        firstInteger * secondInterger = theAnswer;
        return theAnswer;
    }
    if (getFactor == '/')
    {
        firstInteger / secondInterger = theAnswer;
        return theAnswer;
    }
}

int giveResults(int theAnswer)
{
    std::cout << "Your answer is:" + theAnswer;
}
```

The Errors I get:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2106   '=': left operand must be l-value   Calculator2 c:\users\shane\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\calculator2\calculator2\calculationsfunctions.cpp  38

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2106   '=': left operand must be l-value   Calculator2 c:\users\shane\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\calculator2\calculator2\calculationsfunctions.cpp  43

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2106   '=': left operand must be l-value   Calculator2 c:\users\shane\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\calculator2\calculator2\calculationsfunctions.cpp  48

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2106   '=': left operand must be l-value   Calculator2 c:\users\shane\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\calculator2\calculator2\calculationsfunctions.cpp  53

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error (active)      expression must be a modifiable lvalue  Calculator2 c:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Calculator2\Calculator2\CalculationsFunctions.cpp  38

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error (active)      expression must be a modifiable lvalue  Calculator2 c:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Calculator2\Calculator2\CalculationsFunctions.cpp  43

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error (active)      expression must be a modifiable lvalue  Calculator2 c:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Calculator2\Calculator2\CalculationsFunctions.cpp  48

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error (active)      expression must be a modifiable lvalue  Calculator2 c:\Users\Shane\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Calculator2\Calculator2\CalculationsFunctions.cpp  53


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2084   function 'int giveResults(int)' already has a body  Calculator2 c:\users\shane\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\calculator2\calculator2\calculationsfunctions.cpp  59
```

Answer (score 2):

```
firstInteger + secondInterger = theAnswer;
```

That's not how it works, you need to assign to the thing on the *left:*

```
theAnswer = firstInteger + secondInterger;
```

I'm also not certain what you think you're going to achieve with the `factor;` line (among others) in code like:

```
void getFactor(char factor)
{
    factor;
    // blah blah blah
}
```

It's certainly valid but about as useful as `42;` (which is equally valid, by the way).

Answer (score 1):

```
firstInteger + secondInterger = theAnswer;
```

should be

```
theAnswer = firstInteger + secondInterger;
```

Similarly for the other assignments. That's because in C++ an expression of the form `x + y` is a rvalue, i.e., you cannot assign to it (well, unless you redefine the assignment operator, which cannot be done here since you deal with fundamental data types).

Answer (score 0):

Another error is in your `giveResults` method.

This is your current method signature and contents:

```
int giveResults(int theAnswer)
{
    std::cout << "Your answer is:" + theAnswer;
}
```

Its return type is `int` however, you're not returning anything in this situation. It you are simply trying to print it to the console the return type should be `void`. Also `cout` doesn't allow for concatenation of printing items using `+`, you need to change the `cout` call to:

```
std::cout << "Your answer is: " << theAnswer << endl;
```

Using multiple `<<` is the same as using `+` in some other languages for printing to the console, and the `endl` is just to print a new line character at the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys just fixed everything except one error:
Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error C2084 function 'int giveResults(int)' already has a body Calculator2 c:\users\shane\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\calculator2\calculator2\calculationsfunctions.cpp 62

Comment: @ShaneSaunders this is because you've define the `getResults` method inline twice, once at the beginning of calculatorfunctions.cpp and once at the end, I'd suggest deleting the first implementation of it.